# Overriding i18n Messages to use database Play framework

Tags: internationalization, playframework-2.0

In my company they tend to ask some extremly weird features, they want me to load dynamic language files, is there a way to solve this issue without having to rewrite the whole Messages provider of play framework, and instead use some files stored somewhere on the server to handle internationalization?

this could save me a month of work because i've already wrote a huge application (been working on it for a year now) and they want to make all the labels customizable by client.

any help, or any suggestions?

i'm using play framework latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly there is not really much customization options in the Messages API. One idea that might work is to subclass MessagesPlugin with a custom implementation of the api method and provide strings from the database there and then register that as a plugin in your app.